# What is the data type after i open a text in python and how can i get the word inside the txt?

Tags: python, string

Let's said i have a file called `word.txt` and inside the txt file is like this:

```
word=['apple','orange','pear']
```

i want to write some code to get back
`apple orange pear`

but after i write the code and open the file in python like this:

```py
fhand=open('word.txt')
```

but after this i try many method and can't get the result i want.
for example i try

```py
fhand=open('word.txt').read()
```

but this will just give me one string `"word=['apple','orange','pear']"`
so is there a way to somehow split the text after i open the file and get what i want?

Thanks

Comment: learn about [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Syntax). Python comes with the `json` module.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for.

It seems like you want a dictionary with a kehy "word" and values "apple", "orange" and "pear". Is this correct?

If so, you don't need a text document for that.

If you however want a text document and ONLY extract the words "apple", "orange" and "pear" you have to do a while loop and hold the text document open while you (only a suggestion) can use regex to search for the specified words and see if it returns. Regex should return a list with the three words you arer searching for.

Here is a link to a regex cheat sheet.

https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/